# Passing a dynamically created query string for Salesforce application

Tags: performance, visualstudio

I created a web performance test for a Salesforce workflow using visual studio. I created a custom extraction to retrieve a parameter from a query string. However, the request with the query string is after the request that lists the query string parameters. When I attempt to do the extraction before the request, the parameter is not found (which would be expected). After significant research, I haven't been able to find a workaround. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you please add some details about how you're doing extraction?